# In Angular would it be ok/proper to have the constructor above class variables?

Tags: angular, class, syntax, constructor

IE: instead of this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  error_message: string;
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) { }
```

This (Looks cleaner and more proper to me)

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) { }
  users: User[];
  error_message: string;
```

I couldn't find any documentation on this in the Angular style guide: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it okay? Sure it is okay. Is it proper - that is debatable. *It certainly is not conventional.*

**What happens when you start needing to use your member variables in your constructor?**

**In this case:** If you continue to declare your variables below your constructor, sure it will work, but it certainly isn't pleasant for readability. Alternatively in this case you could declare those member variables above your constructor, but then you will have inconsistencies in you files. (i.e. some files with member variables defined before the constructor and some defined after.)

I'd recommend sticking to the convention of defining all your member variables at the beginning of the class prior to the constructor, but hey that is just my two cents! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction for such declaration.

Instead of Angular's style guide, I would advise you to check [TSlint rules](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/)

But there is no such restriction either too

Answer (score 1):

It's ok in the sense that the code will compile and do it's job.
For a typescript linter `tslint` (a program that checks your code for style), the default configuration is to have variables above the constructor.
However, some teams make their own rules. I would suggest to pick an order and stick to it, that makes navigating long files much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the official [angular style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-14).

> Do place properties up top followed by methods.

a Constructor is a method and therefor should be placed after the class's properties.